# Ordered map with independent key equality

Tags: java, data-structures

Is there any implementation of an ordered key-value collection data-structure (like TreeMap or ConcurrentSkipListMap) where the key equality is not dependent on ordering (compareTo / Comparator implementation)?

I agree that most times, these two concepts are connected (and allow for a more performant data structure), but when you want the concept of equality just to enforce key uniqueness it comes handy to separate the two.

Imagine having a class `C` with fields `id` and `rank` that is used as a key in a `Map<C,?>`. Is there a data structure that lets you enforce uniqueness on id (`hashCode` + `equals`) but have the map sorted by rank (`compareTo/comparator`)?

EDIT:
As Sotirios Delimanolis pointed out on his comment, this is conceptually impossible to do with these mechanisms (hashcode/equals/compareTo/comparator) as it would violate their contracts. I guess it would still be possible to do outside of these restrictions, so I'm leaving this open.

Comment: `compareTo` returns 0 for equal operands.

Comment: you are right, and it's also part of the comparator contract.
"consistent with equals if and only if c.compare(e1, e2)==0 has the same boolean value as e1.equals(e2) for every e1 and e2 in S."
Seems that what I'm asking is conceptually impossible, at least with these constructions. Thanks.

Comment: just edited the question to include the limitation you have pointed out.

Comment: If you just include id in the rank calculation would't it solve the problem. When comparator first takes rank into consideration and if and only if ranks are equal then order by id.

Comment: don't think so, as [TreeMap](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8-b132/java/util/TreeMap.java#TreeMap.put%28java.lang.Object%2Cjava.lang.Object%29) uses compareTo == 0 in order to determine equality, so if I wanted to ensure there is only one record with id X, changing the order to consider rank + id would still not identify objects with the same id as equals (they would have to have same rank AND id so the compareTo would return 0, this is not what we want).